# Maven don't add libraries

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I use eclipse and Apachw Maven. I install maven plugin for eclipse. And have project. I add some dependencies for servlet-api into my pom file you can see them :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

I refresh my project, make maven clean and then package but in result I get this:

[image]

so mabe someone can help me? (I can download and add all this libraries in web-inf/lib folder but I don't wan do this)

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: did you try a clean in eclipse. Is it confgured as a maven project in eclipse?

Comment: You shouldn't post images, but rather use the code-markup to make quoting your snippets easier for other people.

Comment: yes I try to clean(I write it in post). yes my project is configured as maven project

Comment: @SpaceTrucker, I want show that this code is underline as error

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using? A Maven plugin comes pre packaged with the IDE as far back as (Galileo?). Try right clicking your project and selecting to update the Maven configuration.

Comment: I use Eclipse Juno. and I download plugin in eclipse marketplace

Comment: When you look at your project properties, in the Libraries tab in Java Build Path, do you see a "Maven Dependencies" folder? And do you see the jars in it?

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak I think my answer should solve your problems, let me know cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the image with the Libraries tab you posted, the project isn't imported as Maven Project, and looks more like a Eclipse Project (Dynamic Web Project), because it doesn't have a "Maven Dependencies" entry.

In this case you can re-import your project with Existing Maven Projects option (not Existing Projects into Workspace) or ...

You can leave it as it is and "Add Library" > "Server runtime" and pick some server instance.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on your project, this will create the .classpath and .project files for your project. You'll also need to rebuild your project in Eclipse by doing **Project -> Clean**

The problem you're having is that the libraries aren't in your .classpath, running eclipse:eclipse should sort this.

.classpath and .project are Eclipse specific files that hold metadata about the project. The .classpath in particular points to where relevant classes are.

See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html for more info.

Comment: at first. I have web app and when I write mvn eclipse:eclipse it is create configuration for simple desctop app. so I think I must write this mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0. I was trying to clean project but this didn't help. at finish I create my web app once more using eclipse and then configurate it in Maven Project. only this helps

Comment: You need to refresh the project and clean-build it from eclipse. When you do mvn eclipse:eclipse it doesn't create a 'simple desktop app', it creates the .project and .classpath files based upon your pom this includes dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Maven project in Eclipse can be a bit tricky. You can try the following steps:

- Build you maven project by command line: in your project folder, type `mvn clean install`
- When the project is successfully built, refresh your project in Eclipse
- Clean your project in Eclipse, in order to rebuild your workspace